# Joining Four Tables without Duplicates From Right Tables in Mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql, left-join, with-statement

I have to fetch data of all users from database, the database structure is as following, which is just few columns from each table, but enough for proof of concept

```
 CREATE TABLE `tblpersonal` (
  `intCompNo` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `strName` varchar(500) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL)


CREATE TABLE `tbledu` (
  `intEduId` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `intCompNo` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `intEduType` varchar(64) COLLATE utf8_bin DEFAULT NULL)


CREATE TABLE `tbltrain` (
  `intTrainId` int(5) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `intCompNo` int(5) NOT NULL,
  `strCourseName` varchar(300) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL)

CREATE TABLE `tblrequests` (
  `intReqId` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `intCompNo` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `strNotes` varchar(512) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
  `dateOfSubmit` datetime NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`intReqId`))
```

now I am running the query below to get the person name, IDs of his education and ID's of his training, and the last request number he has sent

```
SELECT tblpersonal.intCompNo, tblpersonal.strName, tbltrain.intTrainId, tbledu.intEduId, tblrequests.intReqId

FROM tblpersonal

LEFT JOIN tblrequests ON tblpersonal.intCompNo = tblrequests.intCompNo

AND tblrequests.intReqId = (SELECT MAX(req.intReqId) FROM tblrequests AS req WHERE req.intCompNo = tblpersonal.intCompNo)

LEFT JOIN tbltrain ON tblpersonal.intCompNo = tbltrain.intCompNo

LEFT JOIN tbledu ON tblpersonal.intCompNo = tbledu.intCompNo

WHERE tblrequests.intReqId IS NOT NULL

AND tblpersonal.intCompNo = 12368

GROUP BY tblpersonal.intCompNo, tbltrain.intTrainId, tbledu.intEduId

ORDER BY tblpersonal.intCompNo, tbledu.intEduId, tbltrain.intTrainid;
```

the problem is that I have Cartesian product as a result, shows result for only one employee as below

```
+-----------+--------------------------+------------+----------+----------+
| intCompNo | strName                  | intTrainId | intEduId | intReqId |
+-----------+--------------------------+------------+----------+----------+
|     12368 | ????? ???? ???? ???????? |       5194 |      107 |      388 |
|     12368 | ????? ???? ???? ???????? |       5203 |      107 |      388 |
|     12368 | ????? ???? ???? ???????? |       5575 |      107 |      388 |
|     12368 | ????? ???? ???? ???????? |       5580 |      107 |      388 |
|     12368 | ????? ???? ???? ???????? |       5585 |      107 |      388 |
|     12368 | ????? ???? ???? ???????? |       5591 |      107 |      388 |
|     12368 | ????? ???? ???? ???????? |       5636 |      107 |      388 |
|     12368 | ????? ???? ???? ???????? |       5666 |      107 |      388 |
|     12368 | ????? ???? ???? ???????? |       5676 |      107 |      388 |
```

How can I get employee data with all his training and education without duplicates

[Running Example of Database can be found below](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=3b9755b0c887f4055db2abc743cba510)

Comment: I accidentally pressed the submit button before completing the question

Comment: thanks for the advice, I added a fiddle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to be after something like this, which, if not correct, at least has the appearance of a valid query.

```
SELECT DISTINCT p.intCompNo
              , p.strName
              , t.intTrainId
              , e.intEduId
              , r.intReqId  
           FROM tblpersonal p
           LEFT 
           JOIN tblrequests r
             ON r.intCompNo = p.intCompNo 
           JOIN 
              ( SELECT req.intCompNo
                     , MAX(req.intReqId) intreqid
                  FROM tblrequests req 
                 GROUP 
                    BY req.intCompNo 
              ) x 
             ON x.intreqid = r.intReqId 
            AND x.intCompNo = p.intCompNo)
           LEFT 
           JOIN tbltrain t 
             ON t.intCompNo = p.intCompNo 
           LEFT 
           JOIN tbledu e
             ON e.intCompNo = p.intCompNo 
          WHERE r.intReqId IS NOT NULL
            AND p.intCompNo = 12368 
          ORDER 
             BY p.intCompNo
              , e.intEduId
              , t.intTrainid;
```

Comment: @Strawbery , its the same result with Cartesian product

Comment: There's no cartesian product here

Answer (score 2):

If you don't mind a bit of string aggregation

```
SELECT
 tblpersonal.intCompNo
,tblpersonal.strName
,GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT tblrequests.intReqId ORDER BY tblrequests.intReqId SEPARATOR ', ') AS intReqIdList
,GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT tbledu.intEduId ORDER BY tbledu.intEduId SEPARATOR ', ') AS intEduIdList
,GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT tbltrain.intTrainId ORDER BY tbltrain.intTrainId SEPARATOR ', ') AS intTrainIdList
,COUNT(DISTINCT tbltrain.intTrainId) AS intTrainIds
FROM tblpersonal
INNER JOIN tblrequests
  ON tblrequests.intCompNo = tblpersonal.intCompNo
 AND tblrequests.intReqId = (SELECT MAX(req.intReqId) FROM tblrequests AS req WHERE req.intCompNo = tblpersonal.intCompNo)
LEFT JOIN tbltrain
  ON tbltrain.intCompNo = tblpersonal.intCompNo
LEFT JOIN tbledu
  ON tbledu.intCompNo = tblpersonal.intCompNo
WHERE tblpersonal.intCompNo = 12368
GROUP BY
 tblpersonal.intCompNo
,tblpersonal.strName
ORDER BY tblpersonal.intCompNo;
```

**Result:**

> ```
> intCompNo | strName   | intReqIdList | intEduIdList | intTrainIdList                                                                                                                                 | intTrainIds
> --------: | :-------- | :----------- | :----------- | :--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- | ----------:
>     12368 | TEST_USER | 213          | 107, 109     | 5194, 5203, 5575, 5580, 5585, 5591, 5636, 5666, 5676, 5680, 5682, 5685, 5688, 5694, 5700, 5704, 5709, 5713, 5718, 5720, 5722, 5725, 7008, 7014 |          24
> ```

A test on *db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=c597d83c006b3b4f0e524872d500aa9c)*

Or how do you feel about uniting them?

```
SET @CompNo = 12368;
SELECT
 person.intCompNo
,person.strName AS PersonName
,Src.Source
,Src.SrcId
FROM
(
  SELECT req.intCompNo, 'req' AS Source, MAX(req.intReqId) AS SrcId
  FROM tblrequests req
  WHERE req.intCompNo = @CompNo
  GROUP BY req.intCompNo

  UNION ALL

  SELECT train.intCompNo, 'trn', train.intTrainId
  FROM tbltrain AS train
  WHERE train.intCompNo = @CompNo

  UNION ALL

  SELECT edu.intCompNo, 'edu', edu.intEduId
  FROM tbledu AS edu
  WHERE edu.intCompNo = @CompNo
) AS Src
INNER JOIN tblpersonal AS person
        ON Src.intCompNo = person.intCompNo
ORDER BY 
 person.intCompNo, 
 Src.Source, 
 Src.SrcId;
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=84647fe086d786e2a20156f1729c8d34)*

Or maybe this variation of using unions?

```
SET @CompNo = 12368;
SELECT
 person.intCompNo
,person.strName AS PersonName
,Src.intReqId
,Src.intTrainId
,Src.intEduId
FROM
(
  SELECT req.intCompNo
  , MAX(req.intReqId) AS intReqId
  , 0 AS intTrainId
  , 0 AS intEduId
  FROM tblrequests req
  WHERE req.intCompNo = @CompNo
  GROUP BY req.intCompNo

  UNION ALL

  SELECT train.intCompNo
  , 0 AS intReqId
  , train.intTrainId
  , 0 AS intEduId
  FROM tbltrain AS train
  WHERE train.intCompNo = @CompNo

  UNION ALL

  SELECT edu.intCompNo
  , 0 AS intReqId
  , 0 AS intTrainId
  , edu.intEduId
  FROM tbledu AS edu
  WHERE edu.intCompNo = @CompNo
) AS Src
INNER JOIN tblpersonal AS person
        ON Src.intCompNo = person.intCompNo
ORDER BY 
 person.intCompNo,
 Src.intTrainId, Src.intEduId, Src.intReqId;
```

But perhaps you're more looking for a solution like this one that works in MySql 8.0 .
It re-uses a CTE (Common Table Expression).
And uses the window function ROW_NUMBER.
Basically, it links the edu & requests on the same calculated row number of the bigger training table.

```
WITH PERSONAL AS
(
    SELECT intCompNo, strName
    FROM tblpersonal
    WHERE intCompNo IN (12368)
)
SELECT
 person.intCompNo
,person.strName AS PersonName
,req.intReqId
,edu.intEduId
,trn.intTrainId
FROM PERSONAL AS person
LEFT JOIN
(
  SELECT t.intCompNo, t.intTrainId
  , ROW_NUMBER() 
      OVER (PARTITION BY t.intCompNo 
                ORDER BY t.intTrainId) AS rn
  FROM tbltrain AS t
  JOIN PERSONAL p
    ON p.intCompNo = t.intCompNo
) AS trn
ON trn.intCompNo = person.intCompNo
LEFT JOIN
(
  SELECT t.intCompNo
  , MAX(t.intReqId) AS intReqId
  , 1 AS rn
  FROM tblrequests t
  JOIN PERSONAL p
    ON p.intCompNo = t.intCompNo
  GROUP BY t.intCompNo
) AS req
  ON req.intCompNo = trn.intCompNo
 AND req.rn = trn.rn
LEFT JOIN
(
  SELECT t.intCompNo, t.intEduId
  , ROW_NUMBER() 
      OVER (PARTITION BY t.intCompNo 
                ORDER BY t.intEduId) AS rn
  FROM tbledu AS t
  JOIN PERSONAL p
    ON p.intCompNo = p.intCompNo
) AS edu
  ON edu.intCompNo = trn.intCompNo
 AND edu.rn = trn.rn
ORDER BY person.intCompNo;
```

> ```
> intCompNo | PersonName | intReqId | intEduId | intTrainId
> --------: | :--------- | -------: | -------: | ---------:
>     12368 | TEST_USER  |      213 |      107 |       5194
>     12368 | TEST_USER  |     null |      109 |       5203
>     12368 | TEST_USER  |     null |     null |       5575
>     12368 | TEST_USER  |     null |     null |       5580
>     12368 | TEST_USER  |     null |     null |       5585
>     ...
> ```

Test on *db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=979ca12f1a23247148e8398e40e4a8c8)*

Comment: Its a very good solutions, but I am having data exported to excel or PDF, and have to show it as rows,

Comment: Then maybe it's better to export those train & edu & requests separately?  Or maybe using a `UNION ALL` for 3, with an additional source flag?   But when 1 table with N1 rows is joined against 3 tables with N2 & N3 & N4 then it's expected to end up with N1 × N2 × N3 × N4 rows as result.

Comment: @MohammadAwniAli Added an extra solution.

Comment: You are awesome, never think of a solution like this!, the best solution until now, but still need them as rows, Thanks again

Comment: @MohammadAwniAli Just for fun, I included a variation.

Comment: @MohammadAwniAli Added yet another one.  Only for MySql 8.0 though.  MySql 5.7 doesn't have some of the nicer stuff.